# GroupBy with linq method syntax (not query syntax)

Tags: c#, linq, translation, linq-query-syntax

How would the following query look if I was using the extension method syntax?

```
var query = from c in checks
group c by string.Format("{0} - {1}", c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName) 
into customerGroups
select new { Customer = customerGroups.Key, Payments = customerGroups }
```

Comment: For your future reference, this question is answered in the C# 3.0 specification, which you can download off of the internet. All the query transformation rules are specified there.

Comment: ty, didn't know the transformation rules were documented.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
var query = checks
    .GroupBy(c => string.Format("{0} - {1}", c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName))
    .Select (g => new { Customer = g.Key, Payments = g });
```

Answer (score 8):

First, the basic answer:

```
var query = checks.GroupBy<Customer, string>(delegate (Customer c) {
    return string.Format("{0} - {1}", c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName);
}).Select(delegate (IGrouping<string, Customer> customerGroups) {
    return new { Customer = customerGroups.Key, Payments = customerGroups };
});
```

Then, how do you figure out these things yourself?

First, download Reflector from [here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), and install it.

Then build a sample program, like a smallish console program, containing the code you want to analyze. Here's the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public Int32 CustomerId;
        public Int32 CustomerName;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var checks = new List<Customer>();
            var query = from c in checks
                        group c by String.Format("{0} - {1}", c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName)
                            into customerGroups
                            select new { Customer = customerGroups.Key, Payments = customerGroups };
        }
    }
}
```

Then you build that, and open reflector, and ask it to open the .exe file in question.

Then you navigate to the method in question, which in my case was `ConsoleApplication11.Program.Main`.

The trick here is to go to the options page of Reflector, and ask it to show C# 2.0 syntax, which will substitute Linq with the appropriate static method calls. Doing that gives me the following code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Customer> checks = new List<Customer>();
    var query = checks.GroupBy<Customer, string>(delegate (Customer c) {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1}", c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName);
    }).Select(delegate (IGrouping<string, Customer> customerGroups) {
        return new { Customer = customerGroups.Key, Payments = customerGroups };
    });
}
```

Now, of course this code can be written a bit prettier with lambdas and similar, like what [@mquander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55943/mquander) [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967099/groupby-with-linq-method-syntax-not-query-syntax/967108#967108), but with Reflector, at least you should be able to understand the method calls being involved.

Comment: ReSharper also has conversion to/from query syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Since the compiler does this translation for you, fire up [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question, but for new readers, take a look at [this gitub](https://github.com/dudikeleti/Roslyn/tree/master/QueryComprehension) code.

This use Roslyn to take query syntax and convert it to extension method syntax.